# Eclipse with SAP Design Studio SDK - "Missing required bundle"

Tags: eclipse, sdk, business-objects-sdk

I'm trying to develop an plugin for SAP Design Studio using the SDK (which uses eclipse...) and set it up like the documentation says.
When I try to run the plugin via eclipse, I get the following error:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-10-23 14:18:48.915 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are ot >resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-10-23
>   14:18:48.915 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:D:/workspace/com.sap.sample.coloredbox/
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 com.sap.sample.coloredbox 2 0 2013-10-23
>   14:18:48.915 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   com.sap.ip.bi.zen.rt.components.sdk_0.0.0.

So something the bundle "com.sap.ip.bi.zen.rt.components.sdk_0.0.0" seems to be missing - but I don't know where it should come from...
A few weeks ago I've installed the SDK on another machine, and there it's running fine.

I've noticed that in Eclipse (with the sample plugin selected) under "Project->Propertires->Run/Debug Settings", then edit a Launch Configuration, under the fieldset "Program to run" the point "Run a product" is grayed out and has an attention mark which has following hint text:

> "A product with thus name cannot be found in any required bundle. This
>   launch may fail to start as expceted unless there is an avaialable
>   IProductProvider that can supply this product".

On the other machine where the SDK is running, the point is not grayed out and the product "com-sap.ip.bi.zen" is selected.

So the problems seems to be very clear - I only don't know how to resolve it... :/
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

ensure that your plug in design studio target path is valid (preferences -> plug-in development -> target platform).

In my case (win 7 32 bit) I needed to fix the design studio path IMMEDIATELY after pulling in the sdk reference (preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog).  Once eclipse has resolved this it apparently will not do so again if corrections are made.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem with creating a new workspace.